# on a limit of a composition of functions

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow o^{-}} f(x)=a$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow o^{+}} f(x)=b$, and $f(0)=c$ with $a\neq b, a\neq c, b\neq c$, then, what can we say about $\lim_{x\rightarrow o^{-}} f(x^2-x)$ ? Does this limit necessarily exist ? If so, how can we show that by the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument ? Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: HINT: $x^2-x<0$ when $0<x<1$. So $y(x):=x^2-x$ is such that $y(x)\to0^-$ as $x\to0^-$.

Comment: @Nicolas: as $x\to0^-$, we have $x^2-x>0$ and thus $x^2-x\to0^+$.

Comment: @Greg Martin: Thanks for the comment. Now, using the definition of limit, I see that the limit is "$b$". If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes you're right. I have unfortunately edited my comment to write the wrong sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$x^2-x=x(x-1)$$
So, when $ x\to 0^- $,

$x<0 $ and. $ x-1<0 $, thus
$$x^2-x \to 0^+$$
and
$$f(x^2-x)\to b$$
******** * $\epsilon-\delta \; $ proof *****

Given $ \epsilon>0 $,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=b\implies$$
$$\exists \alpha>0\;:\; (0<x<\alpha \implies $$
$$|f(x)-b|<\epsilon)$$

and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}(x^2-x)=0^+\implies$$
$$\exists \delta>0 \;:\; (-\delta<x<0\implies $$
$$0<x^2-x<\alpha)$$

thus
$$\exists \delta>0 \;:\; (-\delta<x<0\implies$$
$$|f(x^2-x)-b|<\epsilon)$$

Which proves that $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x^2-x)=b$.

Comment: I do not see any need of what is written after "Given $\epsilon>0$".

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: In the second and the third parts of your $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, I think it should be $0<0-x<\delta$.

Comment: @serenus Yes, right. Good remark. i edited. thank you very much.